# How to reload an import after updating it? Sage doesn't seem to reload it till end of session

Tags: python-import, reload, sage

I have a file called `MyClass.py` which contains a class `MyClass`.
I have a `MyPrg.sage` which imports this as

```
  from MyClass import MyClass
```

and then instantiates `MyClass` & calls a method on it.

I run `MyPrg.sage` through the sage Console by calling `load`. If after the program exits, I change `MyClass.py` & rerun `MyPrg.sage` again through `load`, it seems to use the older `MyClass.py`. The only way to make it run the updated class is by killing the shell & running it in a new shell.

Is there a way to tell Sage to reload the updated import?

I am running Sage 9.3 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the [`importlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) can be used to reload a module which has already been imported (`importlib.reload(module)`).
However, it is important to note that reloading a module is not always straightforward, especially when dealing with definitions of objects, as *existing* objects will *not* automatically be updated to reflect changes in the module's code.

In [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), you would need to:

- import the `importlib` module in your `MyPrg.sage` file.
- import `MyClass` as a module.
- use `importlib.reload()` to reload the `MyClass` module whenever you have updated `MyClass.py`.

That is:

```py
import importlib
import MyClass

# Load the module initially
my_class_instance = MyClass.MyClass()

# do something

# Now, assume MyClass.py has been updated, and you want to reload it:
importlib.reload(MyClass)

# Now when you create a new instance, it will reflect the updated code:
my_class_instance = MyClass.MyClass()
```

With this setup, each time you call `importlib.reload(MyClass)`, Python will reload the `MyClass` module from `MyClass.py`, reflecting any changes you have made to that file.

---

As mentioned before, any existing instances of `MyClass` will not be updated; only new instances you create *after* reloading the module will reflect the updated code.

Here is an example to illustrate that:

Suppose `MyClass.py` initially looks like:

```py
class MyClass:
    def method(self):
        print("Old Method")
```

And you have a script `MyPrg.sage` that imports `MyClass` and creates an instance:

```py
from MyClass import MyClass

obj = MyClass()
obj.method()  # Outputs: Old Method
```

Now, you update `MyClass.py` to change `method`:

```py
class MyClass:
    def method(self):
        print("New Method")
```

If you reload the `MyClass` module and call `method` on the existing `obj` instance, you will still see the old behavior:

```py
import importlib
import MyClass

importlib.reload(MyClass)
obj.method()  # Outputs: Old Method
```

But if you create a new instance of `MyClass`, you will see the new behavior:

```py
new_obj = MyClass.MyClass()
new_obj.method()  # Outputs: New Method
```

That illustrates how existing objects retain their behavior from before the module was reloaded, while new objects reflect the updated class definitions.

---

> What I want isn't reloading after doing something.
> I want to reload when starting the program itself.
>
> 1. I run `MyPrg`.
> 2. `MyPrg` Finishes execution
> 3. I update `MyClass`.
> 4. I rerun `MyPrg`, the older `MyClass` still seems to be the one which is run
>
> My `MyClass` is `MyClass.py`.
> I import it at top of `MyPrg.sage` as "`from MyClass import MyClass`".
> I instantiate it as `obj = MyClass()`.
>
> When after this I do, `importlib(MyClass)`, I get "`TypeError: reload() argument must be a module`"

When you execute `from MyClass import MyClass`, you are importing the class `MyClass` from the module `MyClass.py`.
However, when you attempt to use `importlib.reload(MyClass)`, it expects a module as an argument, not a class. Hence, you are receiving a `TypeError`.

An alternative way to handle the import such that `importlib.reload()` would be:

1. Modify the import statement in `MyPrg.sage` to import the module `MyClass` instead of importing the class directly from the module.
2. Then, when you instantiate `MyClass`, you will need to qualify it with the module name.
3. Finally, you can use `importlib.reload()` to reload the module.

```py
import importlib
import MyClass  # Import the module, not the class

# Instantiate MyClass from the module
obj = MyClass.MyClass()

# Do something

# Assume MyClass.py has been updated and you want to reload it:
importlib.reload(MyClass)  # That will reload the module

# Now create a new instance, it will reflect the updated code:
new_obj = MyClass.MyClass()
```

In this way, when you make changes to `MyClass.py` and re-run `MyPrg.sage`, the `importlib.reload(MyClass)` statement will reload the updated module `MyClass`.
Any new instances of `MyClass` you create after the reload will reflect the updated code.
That setup should handle the scenario you described, where you update `MyClass.py` between runs of `MyPrg.sage` and want the updated code to be used when you re-run `MyPrg.sage`.

---

The OP adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77221075/how-to-reload-an-import-after-updating-it-sage-doesnt-seem-to-reload-it-till-e/77238816#comment136175980_77238816):

> I didn't need to create a new object because I was re-rerunning the program.
> So I just called `importlib` before creating the object the first time by `obj = MyClass.Class()` and that was enough to refresh the class when re-running the program.

That means the `importlib.reload()` is called each time `MyPrg.sage` is run, making sure the latest version of `MyClass.py` is loaded before creating an object instance. That is a straightforward and effective solution for the described scenario where the program is being re-run and there is a desire to ensure the latest version of `MyClass.py` is used.

This differs from what I suggested: a structure that would allow for module reloading within a running program, which might be more than what is needed for the described scenario.

Comment: What I want isn't reloading after doing something. I want to reload when starting the program itself. 1) I run MyPrg. 2) MyPrg Finishes execution 3) I update MyClass. 4) I rerun MyPrg, the older MyClass still seems to be the one which is run

Comment: My MyClass is MyClass.py. I import it at top of MyPrg.sage as "from MyClass import MyClass". I instantiate it as obj = MyClass(). When after this I do, importlib(MyClass), I get "TypeError: reload() argument must be a module"

Comment: @user93353 OK. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thank you, as said earlier, I didn't need to create a new object because I was re-rerunning the program. So I just called importlib before creating the object the first time by `obj = MyClass.Class()` & that was enough to refresh the class when re-running the program.

Comment: @user93353 Simple and effective, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.